# How can I spy on a class method bound and called in class constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, sinon, es6-class

Say I have an ES6 `Target` class:

```
class Target {

  constructor() {
    this.avoidDetection.bind(this) // not sure if necessary
    this.avoidDetection()
  }

  avoidDetection() {
    console.info('Nobody here but us chickens.')
  }
}
```

...and I want to spy on the `avoidDetection` method when it is invoked inside of the constructor such that:

```
const targetInstance = new Target() // Nobody here but us chickens.

// `spy` is spying on `avoidDetection`

console.log(spy.called === true) // true
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As one React-specific solution, I converted my plain ES6 `Target` class into a child of `React.Component` so that I could take advantage of Enzyme's `instance()` method.  As a result, I got the following to work:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  targetAvoidDetectionSpy = spyOn(Target.prototype, 'avoidDetection')
  targetWrapper = mount(<Target />)
  targetInstance = targetWrapper.instance()
})

it('is an instance of Target', () => {
  expect(targetInstance).toBeInstanceOf(Target)
})

it('avoids detection (not really)', () => {
  expect(targetAvoidDetectionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```